# How can I compare a string and a bool array?

Tags: c#

I have two arrays as below:

```
_user string[3] containing "true" "true" and "true"
_test  bool[3] containing true true false
```

The number of elements in the arrays will vary from one run to another. My question is how can I compare the values in these two arrays and return true if the elements match one for one.

Hope someone can help as my C# is not very good at all.

Janet

Comment: Janet, the solution posted by Thomas Levesque is the better one 'in a vacuum', however there are many things going on there behind the scenes, which might not be entirely clear for a beginner right off the bat. Ron Warholic's solution would probably be easier to understand, as you can trace it step-by-step and see how it works on a somewhat lower level.

Answer (score 13):

Use `bool.Parse` to convert the strings to bool, and `SequenceEqual` to compare the sequences:

```
if (_user.Select(bool.Parse).SequenceEqual(_test))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       bool equal=true;  
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
         if (!( _user[i].equals(Convert.ToString(_test[i]))))
         {
             equal=false;
             break; 
         }

        }
```

or

```
 equal=true;  
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              if !(_test[i]==Convert.ToBoolean(_user[i])))
                  {
                     equal=false;
                     break;
                  } 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the LINQiest but the imperative solution is pretty clear in this case:

```
bool TestItems() {
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(_user.Length, _test.Length); i++) {
    if (_test[i] != (_user[i] == "true")) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

It should be noted without any clarification in the question that this assumes both are the same length and that uneven array lengths will ignore the elements out of bounds of the smaller array.

Comment: Both arrays are the same length. Thanks for your input. Janet

Answer (score 0):

```
            bool [] array1 = {true,false, true};
            bool[] array2 = { true, true, true };
            bool result = false;
            for (int index = 0; index < array1.Length && index < array2.Length; index++)
            { 
                result = CheckTrueOrNot(array1[index],array2[index]);
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }

        private bool CheckTrueOrNot(bool value1, bool value2)
        {
            bool comparisonVal = false;
            if (value1.CompareTo(value2) == 0)
            {
                comparisonVal = true;
            }

            return comparisonVal;
        }
```